# Simple AJAX support for Wicket 1.5.4

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, wicket-1.5

I'm new to wicket and AJAX and trying to set up a simple page that passes messages from the html page via jQuery & ajax to a wicket servlet. The page then updates a label with an appropriate response.

I tried to use the code below from [Marrying Wicket And jQuery UI Autocomplete Ajax](http://thewicketevangelist.blogspot.com/2011/12/marrying-wicket-and-jquery-ui.html) but the code does not compile using Wicket 1.5.4. `getParameterMap()`, `setRequestTarget` and `StringRequestTarget` are all unrecognised in wicket 1.5.4.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
add(aab = new AbstractAjaxBehavior() {

        @Override
        public void renderHead(Component component, IHeaderResponse response) {
            super.renderHead(component, response);
            response.renderJavaScript("var callbackUrl = '" + aab1.getCallbackUrl() + "';", "callbackurl");
        }

        // handle the ajax request
        @Override
        public void onRequest() {
            System.out.println("ajax request received");

            RequestCycle requestCycle = RequestCycle.get();
            Request request = requestCycle.getRequest();
            IRequestParameters irp = request.getRequestParameters();
            String json = getJSON();
            requestCycle.scheduleRequestHandlerAfterCurrent(new TextRequestHandler("application/json", "UTF-8", json));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved as the tutorial code was updated.